# UIView get tap and swipe gestures but set it to ignore pinch to zoom gesture

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have `UIScrollView` and I added `UIView` over it and I added gesture recognizers to `UIView`. I added tap gesture and swipe gestures to `UIView` and it works fine. But when user use pinch then I want to be ignore by `UIView` and `UIScrollView` should react to this gesture. How can I do it? I can't anyway how to do this. I know there is hit test method but I don't think it could help me.

Edit: I have `UIView` at the top which now captures (catch) all gestures. For tap and swipe gestures it's what I want. But I want to pinch gesture would be ignore by top `UIView`and get catched by `UIScrollView` below that `UIView`. I've tried to search for solution but I can't found any.

Comment: The broken English in your question makes your setup and goal unclear. Please refine your question.

Comment: I've edited it and hope now it's more clear what I want.

Comment: 1. Without the gestures added to sub view, does your scroll view get the 'pinch' gesture (like if you are trying to use pinch to zoom .. does it work if you set `userInteractionEnabled=false` for the UIView)

Comment: 2. Add **some** code to your question if you want good answers. Please do not add your entire class. Only the code where you create, add, and handle the gestures (and gesture delegate if relevant)

Comment: Why are you adding an UIView on top of UIScrollView? If it's only to prevent  UIScrollView from getting those gestures, then it's a wrong approach. Describe what do you want to achieve by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the user interaction at any instance by following code:

```
scrollViewObject.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Should help.

Answer (score 0):

If your `UIView` is on top and is capturing all gestures, setup the delegate method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` and get it to detect the type of gesture. If its a `pinch` then call a method on your `UIScrollView`

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UIPinchGestureRecognizer.self) {
        scrollView.someFunction()
    }
    return true
}
```

You can also pass an instance of the pinch gesture to your scrollview function if you wish.